Help with CVXPY multiplication
I am trying to recreate the code from the addendum at the end of this paper in cvxpy (the original is in cvx). Running one iteration seems to work, but the program fails when running the case for count > 0. I am not sure if the way I'm multiplying w0 and ReS together is causing the problem. Using @ returns the error

ValueError: Incompatible dimensions (1, 1) (600, 1),

while using * returns the error

ValueError: The 'maximize' objective must resolve to a scalar.

I am pretty new to using cvxpy so I'm not entirely sure if what I am doing here makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the code:
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

N = 6
M = 200

vc = 1/M * 1/np.tan(np.pi/2/M * np.arange(1, 2*M))
vc[1::2] = 0
vc = np.insert(vc, 0, 0)
Km = toeplitz(vc, np.zeros(2*M))
Km_t = np.transpose(Km)
Km2 = Km - Km_t

# Crossing symmetry matrix
C = np.array([[1/N, N/2 + 1/2 - 1/N, (1 - N)/2],
              [1/N, 1/2 - 1/N, 1/2],
              [-1/N, 1/2 + 1/N, 1/2]])

K = np.kron(np.eye(3), Km2[0:M, 0:M]) + np.kron(C, Km2[0:M, M:])

count = 0
while count < 10:
    ReS = cp.Variable(3*M)
    
    ImS = K@ReS
    constraints = []
    constraints += [cp.abs(ReS+1j*ImS) <=1]
    ReSt = cp.transpose(ReS)
    
    z0 = 0.3j
    zj = np.exp(1j * np.pi / M * np.arange(1, M + 1))
    w1 = 1 / (2 * M) * (1 - (z0 / zj) ** M) * (zj + z0) / (zj - z0)
    w2 = 1 / (2 * M) * (1 - (z0 / zj) ** M) * (zj - z0) / (zj + z0)
    W0 = np.kron(np.eye(3), np.real(w1)) + np.kron(C, np.real(w2))
    v1 = 1 / 2 * (W0[1, :] + W0[2, :])
    v2 = (1 / (2 * N) * W0[0, :] + (1 / 4 - 1 / (2 * N)) * W0[1, :] - 1 / 4 * W0[2, :])
    
    if count == 0:
        t = (v1 - 7.5*v2)@ReSt
    else:
        t = w0*ReS
    
    objective = cp.Maximize(t)
    prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
    result = prob.solve()

    count += 1
    
    V = ReS@np.eye(3*M) + ImS@K
    w0 = np.ones((1,3*M))@V


The MATLAB calculation of V,  is doing implicit expansion of ReS (by repeating the column vector to form a matrix) and then elementwise multiplication (i.e., Hadamard product) of that with eye(3*M). Elementwise multiplication of matrices is different than matrix multiplication. You ought to be able to check the correctness of this without involvement of CVXPY.

Ok that makes sense. I did check it and you're right. Is there any way to replicate the MATLAB effect in python, i.e., expand ReS so that I can take the Hadamard product? I've tried using numpy tile but it doesn't seem to work.

I know MATLAB and CVX, but I'll defer to others on Python. That';s why I just submitted a comment rather than answer.
